# upper case converted to lower case when reading response HEADER in node/express js with httpclients axios and request-promise

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, response-headers

In my application(node/express), I have to call a third party server to read some data. The response of the third party server will have custom header `sessionId` - `Id` being capitalized as per the document. But in my application, the custom header key is changed to `sessionid` - `id` in lowercase. I tested this behaviour in axios and request-promise http client.

Why upper case in header key is converted to lowercase in node/express?

Answer (score 10):

Express's [Request object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) has a case-insensitive `.get('header-name')` method to look up headers.  The way the Express team implemented the case-insensitivity is apparently to downcase the header names in when they store them.

Express does case-insensitive matching here to comply with [RFC2616's specification that header names are to be case-insensitive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-31). That means your third party server is free to return a header named `sessionId`, `sessionid`, `SeSsIoNiD` or whatever, and it still means `sessionid` to your own app. (RFC2616 is the formal specification for the HTTP protocol.)

Comment: Did you mean [`res.get()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.get) for testing a response? Otherwise, not understanding the use-case for getting the `Request` Headers, which should have been added via `req.set()`